# How to set the value of PATH variable in a virtualenv?

Tags: django, environment-variables, virtualenv

I have installed virtualenv and created a virtualenv directory for testing out the newer development version of django.I git cloned the latest version of django and placed .pth file inside the virtualenv's site package directory to the cloned django dir.Now I need to modify the PATH variable(to include django/bin) so that  django-admin.py is accessible from the virtualenv.How can i do it?

My current PATH in virtualenv includes a directory

> django/core/django/bin

Why does it include it ? 
I haven't done any modification to PATH right now.

--I've given the relative path of the django directory here instead of the fullpath to mimnimize the clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's far easier to `pip install` using the repo itself. Then, all the linking is done for you automatically:

Just use:

```
$ pip install svn+http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/#egg=django
```

And, you're ready to roll.

Comment: `git+http://path/to/git/repo`... However, Django's official repo is *Subversion*. Whatever repo you're using that uses git, is definitely use at your own risk.

Comment: This one is the git clone of the official repository.https://github.com/django/django

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, then, but still, for installing Django there's really no reason to not use the official SVN repo. The git version is likely just for easy submoduling in a app that merely uses pieces of Django functionality. For instance, a Tornado app that uses the Django DBAPI and perhaps Django templating.